# Entity Framework Core Add entity with dependecy that is saved throws the error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have something like this entities:

```cs
class Store
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<StoreItem> Items { get; set; }
    ...
}
class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
}
class StoreItem 
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public Item Item { get; set; }
    public int StoreId { get; set; }
    public Store Store { get; set; }
}
```

When I added to store saved item and then try to add it to DbSet:

```cs
Item item = new Item()
{
    ...
};
using (var transaction = _dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    await _dbContext.Items.AddAsync(item); // The item is stored in store StoreItem
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
...
Store store = new Store()
{
    ...
};
store.Items = new List<StoreItem>()
{
    new StoreItem()
    {
        ItemId = item.Id,
        Item = item,
        Store = store,
    }
};
using (var transaction = _dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    await _dbContext.Stores.AddAsync(store);
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

this code throws exception that:

```
The instance of entity type 'Item' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.
```

I cannot get how to add new Store that have dependency on already saved Item ??

Issue is reproducible on PostgresSQL, here is project example https://github.com/redradist/SO-ReproducedExample

Comment: Where do you get the `store.Item` from? It seems it has been set with an entity, that is not being tracked by EF Core and when you add the `store`, the `store.Item` will be added as well, but conflicts with an already tracked version of the `Item` (with the same `Id`).

Comment: It's really very simple. Remove the first add and the first save. Now go and read the documentation for both methods thoroughly

Comment: But if I save item first ... than after some time store decided to add this item that is already saved to _dbContext.Items ?? It is valid use-case

Comment: Yes but you should use a different DB context or you need to use attach.

Comment: Why I cannot use the same DB context ? I have in the same DBContext different tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was due to that in example https://github.com/redradist/SO-ReproducedExample I used different objects for the same Many-to-Many relationship:

```cs
var storesForItem1 = new List<StoreItemEntity>()
{
    new StoreItemEntity()
    {
        ItemId = item1Entity.Id,
        Item = item1Entity,
        Store = storeEntity,
    }
};
var storesForItem2 = new List<StoreItemEntity>()
{
    new StoreItemEntity()
    {
        ItemId = item2Entity.Id,
        Item = item2Entity,
        Store = storeEntity,
    }
};
var itemsForStore = new List<StoreItemEntity>()
{
    new StoreItemEntity()  // <-- Issue, should be used previous created StoreItemEntity for this relationship
    {
        Item = item1Entity,
        StoreId = storeEntity.Id,
        Store = storeEntity,
    },
    new StoreItemEntity()  // <-- Issue, should be used previous created StoreItemEntity for this relationship
    {
        Item = item2Entity,
        StoreId = storeEntity.Id,
        Store = storeEntity,
    }
};
```

You should use only one entity instance with the same key for particular object

Here is fixed implementation in branch `fixed-example`:

https://github.com/redradist/SO-ReproducedExample/tree/feature/fixed-example

Answer (score 0):

`DbSet<T>.Add` will assume that all objects that have not been tracked yet are new.

If you want to attach your Item as an existing item, you should do that first, or use `context.ChangeTracker.TrackGraph()` so you can specify how each object should be attached.

Comment: What if only store is not tracking, but direct dependency Item is already tracking ?

Answer (score -1):

**- 1**

Most of the time this exception is related with `Service Registration`

And most likely - because you didnt provide more information - your repository/service is registered as a singleton lifetime

-> `Startup.cs` - `services.AddSingleton<IRepository, Repository>();`

You have to change it to `services.AddScoped<IRepository, Repository>();`

**- 2**

This could be happening because of you are sharing your entity accross multiple `DbContext` objects.

Please try to use one context for your method.

**- 3**

`AsNoTracking()`could be helpful, but while you are adding a new entity I don't think that this is the best situation.

Among all of the above, I think the source of the problem is what I explained in the **1st** point.

Comment: I am doing something like this with EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite without any services: await _dbContext.Items.AddAsync(item); // The item is stored in store StoreItem
await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
...
await _dbContext.Stores.AddAsync(store);
await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

Comment: Thank you for editing your answer, now could you please share your whole code where you are adding the entities, I have to see the AddAsync(item) - item and AddAsync(store) -store entities and how did you set them

Comment: I have update question that you can see how I set Store item

Comment: I've prepared a working sample, could you please check it. https://github.com/bkarakaya01/SO-ReproducedExample

Comment: Yes, the example looks nice ... One difference is that I commit also asynchronously, but I do not think that it is matter

Comment: Yeah, that wont be a problem, and now I realised that you said Sqlite, not SqlServer, but it shouldn't also be a problem, because it is entityframework related anyway. :)

Comment: But it is an issue ( I also thought that it should work, but it is not ( You can check it with say simple Xamarin application

Comment: Sorry, couldnt understand the issue, which one is not working for you?

Comment: Oh, actually this is a good point for this situation, now its reproducable

Comment: I have reproduced the issue on your example https://github.com/redradist/SO-ReproducedExample

Comment: Thanks, I’m going to take a look as soon as possible

Comment: Have you saw example that I provided ?